# Use mysqldump to backup table with a new table name

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

Is there a way to back up a table using `mysqldump` so the table that is being backed up can have a new name in the `sql` script created by mysqldump.

So that If I back up the table 'test_table' like so.

```
mysqldump -u user -p db_name test_table > backup.sql
```

and I want 'test_table' to now be called 'test_table_backup' in the `backup.sql` that is created.

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table_backup` (

...

);
```

I know i can just dump the file then craft some way to do a search and replace on the table name but I was hoping there was a safer way using mysqldump itself.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) to transform the table name

```
mysqldump -u user -p db_name test_table | sed 's/test_table/test_table_backup/g' > backup.sql
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: The sed command won't catch `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ...;` line, because it doesn't have space after the ending tick. You can remove the space at the end of the sed command, but I would still be extra careful with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

sed is a simple way to to change the table name (as mentioned in the other Answer). If you are worried that table_name may appear as part of the table data, you can add backtick back spaces to be more precise with your sed statement. This works because mysqldump always surrounds the table name with backtick and spaces.

```
mysqldump -u username -p db_name table_name | sed -e 's/ `table_name` / `table_name_new` /' > dump_table_new.sql
```

Of course, if you already have a dump file, you don't need to run mysqldump again.

```
sed -e 's/ `table_name` / `table_name_new` /' < dump_table_name.sql > dump_table_new.sql
```

If you want to copy a table without mysqldump, then I would suggest [pt-table-sync in the Percona toolkit](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/3.0/pt-table-sync.html).

Comment: The spaces inside your `sed` statement will cause it not to match the table names as intended, as the backticks do not always have a space before/after them.